# How to generate all elements of an extension field from a base field? (GF(2))

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

I am trying to understand how to show something is a primitive polynomial; I understand it has to be irreducible by definition, and according to Wolfram:

```
A primitive polynomial is a polynomial that generates all elements of an extension field from a base field.
```

For example, the polynomial
$1 + x + x^2$ is primitive over $GF(2^3)$. What is the rudimentary way of generating the elements of $GF(2^3)$ from this polynomial? My knowledge is not in a math-focused field so I just need a straightforward methodology for generating the elements to show polynomials are primitive under $GF(2^m)$.

Comment: "Generates" is vague here. With the usual definition of "generates" this is not the correct definition of a primitive polynomial. Wikipedia has the correct definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory) ). Here is a test: a polynomial is primitive for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ iff it divides the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^n - 1}(x) \bmod p$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). These can be computed pretty quickly as long as $p, n$ aren't too big by a suitable recursion.